# Criar coluna com valores condicionais aos de outra coluna

Tags: r

Supondo a seguinte coluna com ações:

### ## codigo##

### petr

### mils

### oibr

Eu gostaria de saber como criar uma outra coluna onde os valores seriam condicionais aos da coluna "código'. Exemplo:

```
if codigo='petr' then nova_coluna = 'baixo risco'
if codigo='mils' then nova_coluna = 'alto risco'
if codigo='oibr' then nova_coluna = 'especulacao'
```

Comment: Quando diz que tem uma *coluna*, isso significa que tem um objeto de classe `"data.frame"` (ou uma tabela) com uma coluna chamada `codigo`?

Answer (score 1):

Vou supor que tem uma tabela com uma coluna chamada `codigo` com os valores da pergunta.

**Solução R base.**

O código seguinte começa por criar uma coluna `nova_coluna` toda com o mesmo valor, `'baixo risco'`. Depois modifica cada um dos valores correspondentes aos valores `'mils'` e `'oibr'` da coluna `codigo`.

```
dados$nova_coluna <- 'baixo risco'
dados$nova_coluna[dados$codigo == 'mils'] <- 'alto risco'
dados$nova_coluna[dados$codigo == 'oibr'] <- 'especulacao'

head(dados)
#  codigo nova_coluna
#1   mils  alto risco
#2   mils  alto risco
#3   petr baixo risco
#4   oibr especulacao
#5   petr baixo risco
#6   petr baixo risco
```

**Solução `dplyr`.**

Esta solução parece ser mais legível, mais de acordo com o modo como está formulada a pergunta.

```
library(dplyr)

dados <- dados %>%
  mutate(nova_coluna = case_when(
    codigo == 'petr' ~ 'baixo risco',
    codigo == 'mils' ~ 'alto risco',
    codigo == 'oibr' ~ 'especulacao',
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ))
```

**Dados de teste.**

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 20
dados <- data.frame(codigo = sample(c('petr', 'mils', 'oibr'), n, TRUE))
```